# Django Sb Admin 2 Pandas

Tags: bootstrap, django, pandas

Estoy realizando un portal estadístico, con Django y para los cálculos quiero usar Pandas, estoy probando mostrar algunas tablas de la siguiente manera:

Views.py

```
def tabla(request):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxxx@localhost:5432/escaladas')
    t='escalado 08/2017'
    sqltable = ps.read_sql_table(t,engine)
    sqltablehead = sqltable.head(n=10)
    table = sqltablehead.to_html(classes='table',index=False,escape=False)
    return render(request,'escalamiento.html',{'table':table})
```

Estoy usando `Bootstrap` Sb Admin 2 para la interfaz gráfica y me gustaría mostrar esa tabla con el aspecto que me facilita Sb Admin 2 pero no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, he intentado escribir `{{table}}` pero me muestra lo siguiente sin el formato de tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y también lo intenté con un `for`, pero no me muestra nada (cabe destacar que lo puedo estar haciendo mal, soy nuevo con Django y Bootstrap). ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución. Se debe colocar de la siguiente manera `{{table|safe}}`. para que el HTML no se  [Escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Comment: Hola Anthony. Me alegra ver que encontraste la solución al problema. Te comento que, aunque la respuesta es correcta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Trata de añadir algún comentario sobre por qué funciona así y no como tenías, o un enlace a la documentación donde se explique esto para completarla un poco.